# Dask distributed problem: shuffle_transfer failed during shuffle

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I don't know which part is not correct, at the first, I create a clusters on AWS with `cloud-provider` library, then I run `tsfresh` library to extract features. And I got this error.

```py
from dask_cloudprovider.aws import FargateCluster
from distributed import Client

cluster = FargateCluster(
    n_workers=2,
    worker_mem=1024*8,
    image="dask-tslearn:latest",
    fargate_spot=True,
    task_role_policies=["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"],
)
client = Client(cluster)
client
```

Then, I run below:

```py
cluster.scale(50)

from tsfresh.feature_extraction import EfficientFCParameters

settings = EfficientFCParameters()
assert "matrix_profile" not in settings

import dask.dataframe as dd
from tsfresh import extract_features

df = dd.read_parquet("s3://**/")

X = extract_features(
    df,
    column_id="meter_id",
    column_sort="iso_datetime",
    chunksize=1,
    default_fc_parameters=settings,
)

result = X.compute()
```

then, the code failed because of error:

```bash
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [11], line 7
      3 from tsfresh import extract_features
      5 df = dd.read_parquet("s3***")
----> 7 X = extract_features(
      8     df,
      9     column_id="id",
     10     column_sort="***",
     11     chunksize=1,
     12     default_fc_parameters=EfficientFCParameters(),
     13 )
     15 result = X.compute()

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/extraction.py:164, in extract_features(timeseries_container, default_fc_parameters, kind_to_fc_parameters, column_id, column_sort, column_kind, column_value, chunksize, n_jobs, show_warnings, disable_progressbar, impute_function, profile, profiling_filename, profiling_sorting, distributor, pivot)
    161 else:
    162     warnings.simplefilter("default")
--> 164 result = _do_extraction(
    165     df=timeseries_container,
    166     column_id=column_id,
    167     column_value=column_value,
    168     column_kind=column_kind,
    169     column_sort=column_sort,
    170     n_jobs=n_jobs,
    171     chunk_size=chunksize,
    172     disable_progressbar=disable_progressbar,
    173     show_warnings=show_warnings,
    174     default_fc_parameters=default_fc_parameters,
    175     kind_to_fc_parameters=kind_to_fc_parameters,
    176     distributor=distributor,
    177     pivot=pivot,
    178 )
    180 # Impute the result if requested
    181 if impute_function is not None:

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/extraction.py:304, in _do_extraction(df, column_id, column_value, column_kind, column_sort, default_fc_parameters, kind_to_fc_parameters, n_jobs, chunk_size, disable_progressbar, show_warnings, distributor, pivot)
    301 if not pivot:
    302     return result
--> 304 return_df = data.pivot(result)
    305 return return_df

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/data.py:413, in DaskTsAdapter.pivot(self, results)
    404 """
    405 The extract features function for dask returns a
    406 dataframe of [id, variable, value].
   (...)
    410 Attention: this is highly non-optimized!
    411 """
    412 results = results.reset_index(drop=True).persist()
--> 413 results = results.categorize(columns=["variable"])
    414 feature_table = results.pivot_table(
    415     index=self.column_id, columns="variable", values="value", aggfunc="sum"
    416 )
    418 return feature_table

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py:5255, in DataFrame.categorize(self, columns, index, split_every, **kwargs)
   5253 @wraps(categorize)
   5254 def categorize(self, columns=None, index=None, split_every=None, **kwargs):
-> 5255     return categorize(
   5256         self, columns=columns, index=index, split_every=split_every, **kwargs
   5257     )

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/dataframe/categorical.py:152, in categorize(df, columns, index, split_every, **kwargs)
    149 dsk.update(df.dask)
    151 # Compute the categories
--> 152 categories, index = compute_as_if_collection(
    153     df.__class__, dsk, (prefix, 0), **kwargs
    154 )
    156 # some operations like get_dummies() rely on the order of categories
    157 categories = {k: v.sort_values() for k, v in categories.items()}

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/base.py:341, in compute_as_if_collection(cls, dsk, keys, scheduler, get, **kwargs)
    339 schedule = get_scheduler(scheduler=scheduler, cls=cls, get=get)
    340 dsk2 = optimization_function(cls)(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
--> 341 return schedule(dsk2, keys, **kwargs)

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/client.py:3136, in Client.get(self, dsk, keys, workers, allow_other_workers, resources, sync, asynchronous, direct, retries, priority, fifo_timeout, actors, **kwargs)
   3134         should_rejoin = False
   3135 try:
-> 3136     results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous, direct=direct)
   3137 finally:
   3138     for f in futures.values():

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/client.py:2305, in Client.gather(self, futures, errors, direct, asynchronous)
   2303 else:
   2304     local_worker = None
-> 2305 return self.sync(
   2306     self._gather,
   2307     futures,
   2308     errors=errors,
   2309     direct=direct,
   2310     local_worker=local_worker,
   2311     asynchronous=asynchronous,
   2312 )

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/utils.py:338, in SyncMethodMixin.sync(self, func, asynchronous, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    336     return future
    337 else:
--> 338     return sync(
    339         self.loop, func, *args, callback_timeout=callback_timeout, **kwargs
    340     )

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/utils.py:405, in sync(loop, func, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    403 if error:
    404     typ, exc, tb = error
--> 405     raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
    406 else:
    407     return result

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/utils.py:378, in sync.<locals>.f()
    376         future = asyncio.wait_for(future, callback_timeout)
    377     future = asyncio.ensure_future(future)
--> 378     result = yield future
    379 except Exception:
    380     error = sys.exc_info()

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/gen.py:769, in Runner.run(self)
    766 exc_info = None
    768 try:
--> 769     value = future.result()
    770 except Exception:
    771     exc_info = sys.exc_info()

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/lake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/client.py:2168, in Client._gather(self, futures, errors, direct, local_worker)
   2166         exc = CancelledError(key)
   2167     else:
-> 2168         raise exception.with_traceback(traceback)
   2169     raise exc
   2170 if errors == "skip":

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/shuffle/_shuffle.py:71, in shuffle_transfer()

RuntimeError: shuffle_transfer failed during shuffle c1992000bcde9deee65a2332ab4614a2
```

below is my package version.

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- -----------
aiobotocore                   2.4.2
aiohttp                       3.8.4
aioitertools                  0.11.0
aiosignal                     1.3.1
anyio                         3.6.2
appnope                       0.1.3
argon2-cffi                   21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings          21.2.0
asttokens                     2.2.1
async-timeout                 4.0.2
attrs                         22.2.0
backcall                      0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache 1.6.4
beautifulsoup4                4.11.2
bleach                        6.0.0
bokeh                         2.4.3
botocore                      1.27.59
brotlipy                      0.7.0
certifi                       2022.12.7
cffi                          1.15.1
charset-normalizer            2.1.1
click                         8.1.3
cloudpickle                   2.2.1
colorama                      0.4.6
comm                          0.1.2
cryptography                  39.0.1
cytoolz                       0.12.0
dask                          2023.3.0
dask-cloudprovider            2022.10.0
debugpy                       1.6.6
decorator                     5.1.1
defusedxml                    0.7.1
distributed                   2023.3.0
entrypoints                   0.4
executing                     1.2.0
fastjsonschema                2.16.3
flit_core                     3.8.0
frozenlist                    1.3.3
fsspec                        2023.1.0
HeapDict                      1.0.1
idna                          3.4
importlib-metadata            6.0.0
importlib-resources           5.12.0
ipykernel                     6.21.2
ipython                       8.11.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
jedi                          0.18.2
Jinja2                        3.1.2
jmespath                      1.0.1
joblib                        1.2.0
jsonschema                    4.17.3
jupyter_client                8.0.3
jupyter_core                  5.2.0
jupyter-events                0.6.3
jupyter_server                2.3.0
jupyter_server_terminals      0.4.4
jupyterlab-pygments           0.2.2
llvmlite                      0.39.1
locket                        1.0.0
lz4                           4.3.2
MarkupSafe                    2.1.2
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
mistune                       2.0.5
msgpack                       1.0.4
multidict                     6.0.4
nbclassic                     0.5.2
nbclient                      0.7.2
nbconvert                     7.2.9
nbformat                      5.7.3
nest-asyncio                  1.5.6
notebook                      6.5.2
notebook_shim                 0.2.2
numba                         0.56.4
numpy                         1.23.5
packaging                     23.0
pandas                        1.5.3
pandocfilters                 1.5.0
parso                         0.8.3
partd                         1.3.0
patsy                         0.5.3
pexpect                       4.8.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        9.4.0
pip                           23.0.1
pkgutil_resolve_name          1.3.10
platformdirs                  3.0.0
pooch                         1.7.0
prometheus-client             0.16.0
prompt-toolkit                3.0.38
psutil                        5.9.4
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
pure-eval                     0.2.2
pyarrow                       11.0.0
pycparser                     2.21
Pygments                      2.14.0
pyOpenSSL                     23.0.0
pyrsistent                    0.19.3
PySocks                       1.7.1
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-json-logger            2.0.7
pytz                          2022.7.1
PyYAML                        6.0
pyzmq                         25.0.0
requests                      2.28.2
rfc3339-validator             0.1.4
rfc3986-validator             0.1.1
s3fs                          2023.1.0
scikit-learn                  1.2.1
scipy                         1.10.1
Send2Trash                    1.8.0
setuptools                    67.4.0
six                           1.16.0
sniffio                       1.3.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
soupsieve                     2.3.2.post1
stack-data                    0.6.2
statsmodels                   0.13.5
stumpy                        1.11.1
tblib                         1.7.0
terminado                     0.17.1
threadpoolctl                 3.1.0
tinycss2                      1.2.1
toolz                         0.12.0
tornado                       6.2
tqdm                          4.64.1
traitlets                     5.9.0
tsfresh                       0.20.0
typing_extensions             4.4.0
urllib3                       1.26.14
wcwidth                       0.2.6
webencodings                  0.5.1
websocket-client              1.5.1
wheel                         0.38.4
wrapt                         1.15.0
yarl                          1.8.2
zict                          2.2.0
zipp                          3.15.0
```

and the package used for cluster worker:

```
ARG BASE_CONTAINER=condaforge/mambaforge:latest
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 $BASE_CONTAINER 

ARG python=3.10.8
ARG release=2023.3.0

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH
ENV PYTHON_VERSION=${python}
ENV DASK_VERSION=${release}

RUN mamba install -y \
    "mamba>=0.27.0" \
    python=${PYTHON_VERSION} \
    tsfresh \
    pyarrow \
    s3fs \
    nomkl \
    cmake \
    dask=${DASK_VERSION} \
    cachey \
    streamz \
    && mamba clean -tipy \
    && find /opt/conda/ -type f,l -name '*.a' -delete \
    && find /opt/conda/ -type f,l -name '*.pyc' -delete \
    && find /opt/conda/ -type f,l -name '*.js.map' -delete \
    && find /opt/conda/lib/python*/site-packages/bokeh/server/static -type f,l -name '*.js' -not -name '*.min.js' -delete \
    && rm -rf /opt/conda/pkgs

COPY prepare.sh /usr/bin/prepare.sh

RUN mkdir /opt/app

ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "-g", "--", "/usr/bin/prepare.sh"]
```

Comment: Hi @Yiffany, it's a bit hard to tell without a Minimal Reproducer (i.e. without Fargate and with some dataset). We can only see that the code is failing on a pivot_table operation, which involve shuffling data between Dask Worker. The problem is not necessarily your code, but it can come from the dataset, or the operations that your trying to do on this dataset which involve too much data transfer.

Comment: @GuillaumeEB, Reproducer updated in [github issue](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/7615) please have a check.

Comment: Did you try the code with a LocalCluster and just a subset of the input dataset? How large is the input dataset?

Comment: Yes, local cluster works fine.

Comment: With the complete dataset?

Comment: yes, complete dataset works fine with local cluster.

Comment: What is your configuration for LocalCluster? Did you try to use the same one (same number of workers/memory) with Fargate?

Comment: Was this resolved?

Comment: @jsanjayce, yes https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/7615#issuecomment-1487839892

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'm facing this same error still with the latest dask and distributed version in groupby operation.